# TFS in Visual Studio: Exclude specific branches from update

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013, source-control-explorer

I'm using TFS Source Control within the Visual Studio. We've a folder with a lot of branches in it. When I right click on the folder an select "Get latest version", all branches are downloaded. How can I exclude branches from being updated? Update every included branch manually seems to be to tedious.
Thanks
Konrad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I found out: I can cloak single folders and branches ... that excludes them from being updated.
http://blogs.objectsharp.com/post/2012/11/13/Cloaked-folders-in-the-TFS-Build-Workspace.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could create a batch file including a get latest for all required branches. See the [get](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) command.